# Using SUBSTITUTE with wildcard characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

To illustrate my issue, use the following simple example.

I want to be able to replace any text that comes between "replace" and "that" to "it is done". For example, the two following strings:

```
blah blah blah replace this and that blah
blah blah blah replace this and some other text and that blah
```

to this string

```
blah blah blah it is done blah
```

using the SUBSTITUTE function in excel using wildcard characters.

This is the formula that I'm using:

```
=SUBSTITUTE("blah blah blah replace this and that blah","replace*that","it is done")
```

The formula isn't replacing the text, though, and evaluates to "blah blah blah replace this and that blah"

What is going on?

Comment: The `SUBSTITUTE` formula doesn't work with wildcards. You'll have to build up a solution by using `FIND` to locate the first word and the last word, then probably use `REPLACE`. Something like `=REPLACE(A1,FIND("replace",A1,1),FIND("that",A1,1)-FIND("replace",A1,1)+4,"it is done")`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you can use `SUBSTITUTE` with wildcards.

But you can use `FIND` to get the location of those words within the text, then `LEFT` and `RIGHT` to get the text outside of those words.

For example:

```
= LEFT(A1,FIND("replace",A1)-1)&"it is done"&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("that",A1)-3)
```

Note `FIND("replace",B4)-1` gets the location of the character right before "replace".

And `LEN(B4)-FIND("that",B4)-3` gets the location of the character right after "that".

Answer (score 2):

Both SUBSTITUTE and REPLACE functions will select a string within your text and update accordingly. However, the REPLACE function replaces the string based on its position.

```
=REPLACE(A1,SEARCH("replace",A1),SEARCH("that",A1)+ 4-SEARCH("replace",A1),"it is done")
```

You can use the SEARCH function to find the first word and then the length of the string that you want replaced.